# Give a lower bound of $T$ if $\log T / T \leq \epsilon^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, computer-science, computational-complexity

Let $T>10$. Give a tighter lower bound of $T$ if $\log T / T \leq \epsilon^{2}$.

I know that $T$ should be in the order of $\widetilde{O}(\epsilon^{-2})$. How can we prove this?

Suppose $T = A \epsilon^{-2+\delta}$.

We then have $\frac{\log T \epsilon^{-2}}{T} = \frac{(-2+\delta) \log \epsilon + log A}{A\epsilon^{\delta}} \rightarrow \infty$ if $\delta>0$.

So $\delta$ must be zero. But this does not give a lower bound of $T.$

Comment: Using Lambert W function, if $\epsilon^2 \le \mathrm{e}^{-1}$, the solution to the equation $\frac{\ln T}{T} = \epsilon^2$ is given by $T = -\mathrm{LambertW}(-1, -\epsilon^2)/\epsilon^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @RiverLi commented
$$\frac{\log(T)} T=\epsilon^2 \quad \implies \quad T=-\frac{W_{-1}\left(-\epsilon ^2\right)}{\epsilon ^2}$$ where $W$ is the second branch of Lambert function.

In year $2016$,  [Chatzigeorgiou](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.04895.pdf) proved that, if $u>0$,

$$-1 - \sqrt{2u} - u < W_{-1}\left(-e^{-u-1}\right) < -1 - \sqrt{2u} - \frac{2}{3}u$$

Let $u=-(2 \log (\epsilon )+1)$ to obtain two simple bounds for $T$

Comment: It is nice bound for $W_{-1}$.

Comment: @RiverLi. Not only nice but extremely useful (and very recent). Cheers :-)